# How to Encrypt traffic between barebone node TCP socket?

Tags: node.js, ssl, encryption, tcp, tcpclient

I want to encrypt the traffic between **TCP** **socket server** and **TCP** **socket client**. I have no idea how to achieve this or move forward any direction will help. I'm using node js `'net'` module for tcp server.
Thank you!

Comment: Have you investigated nodejs's [Transport Layer Security package](https://nodejs.org/dist./v8.14.1/docs/api/tls.html#tls_tls_ssl)? It's worth noting that doing this correctly and securely is very hard; it may be easier for you to use [secure Websockets](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws) layered on https.

Comment: Need to dig into nodes TLS package, Where the application is using can not use websokcet, i had to use tcp socket. Thanks for your answer @O.Jones